# Bokeh Label font size responsive to figure size

Tags: python, responsive-design, bokeh, python-3.7

I was adding a label as an annotation to a figure. I can set the font size of the label upfront. However, when the size of the browser is adjusted, only the size of the figure is reponsive, the font size of the label is un-responsive.

```
fig = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', y_axis_label=labels[i],
             toolbar_location=None, active_drag=None, 
             active_scroll=None)
fig.line(x='time', y='data', source=source, line_color='red')
annotation = Label(x=10, y=10, text='text', text_font_size='60px', text_color='white', x_units='screen', y_units='screen', background_fill_color=None))
```

I tried to adjust the font size using the height of the figure, but this does not work. Is there a way to achieve this purpose? Thank you for any hint/help.

```
annotation.text_font_size = str(fig.plot_height * 0.1)+'px'
```

Comment: Can you try using relative units for the font size, e.g. `rem` instead of `px`?

Comment: Thanks, I tried '10rem' but with luck :(

Comment: I tried 'vw' and it works. From one of your [answers](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/keep-axis-and-font-size-proportion-when-exporting-bigger-plots-with-export-png/4044/2?u=user4015990).

Comment: Great can you post and accept a complete example as a self answer to help others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue more about css rather than bokeh itself. From [here](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/keep-axis-and-font-size-proportion-when-exporting-bigger-plots-with-export-png/4044/2?u=user4015990), one has a broad range of selections for the unit of the font size. For my situation, 'vh' will do the trick and the font size is now responsive to the dimension of the browser. For example:

```python
annotation = Label(x=10, y=10, text='text', text_font_size='10vh', text_color='white', x_units='screen', y_units='screen', background_fill_color=None))
```

Standalone example:

```
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Label
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from functools import partial
import time

def f_emitter(p=0.1):
    v = np.random.rand()
    return (dt.datetime.now(), 0. if v>p else v)


def make_document(doc, functions, labels):
    def update():
        for index, func in enumerate(functions):
            data = func()
            sources[index].stream(new_data=dict(time=[data[0]], data=[data[1]]), rollover=1000)
            annotations[index].text = f'{data[1]: .3f}'
            # print(figs[index].height)

    sources = [ColumnDataSource(dict(time=[], data=[])) for _ in range(len(functions))]
    figs = []
    annotations = []
    for i in range(len(functions)):
        figs.append(figure(x_axis_type='datetime',
                       y_axis_label=labels[i], toolbar_location=None,
                       active_drag=None, active_scroll=None))
        figs[i].line(x='time', y='data', source=sources[i])
        annotations.append(Label(x=10, y=10, text='', text_font_size='10vh', text_color='black',
                             x_units='screen', y_units='screen', background_fill_color=None))
        figs[i].add_layout(annotations[i])


    doc.add_root(column([fig for fig in figs], sizing_mode='stretch_both'))
    doc.add_periodic_callback(callback=update, period_milliseconds=100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # list of functions and labels to feed into the scope
    functions = [f_emitter]
    labels = ['emitter']

    server = Server({'/': partial(make_document, functions=functions, labels=labels)})
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    try:
        server.io_loop.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('keyboard interruption')
```